# JSON-LD error in SDTT when using types inside of other types: "Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration."

Tags: json, json-ld

I'm currently trying to apply both `WebSite` and `Organization` Schema.org via JSON-LD using `@graph`, and I'm running into issues with syntax that I don't understand.  I'm not a Javascript developer, just a HTML & CSS guy, so I really can't figure out what's going on.

In Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, I'm getting errors on line 11:

> Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration.

but I've gone through it multiple times and I can't understand the problem. I've tried rearranging all of the brackets and moving things around here and there and it seems like every time I eliminate the error, another error arises. This is the best version of the code I've got so far.

It seems like the problem comes in when using `@type` inside of other `@type`s.

```json
{
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@graph" : 
        [
            {
                "@type" : "WebSite", 
                "url" : "https://www.bcsauto.com", 
                "name" : "BCS Auto",
                "author" : 
                    [
                        "@type" : "Person",
                        "name" : "Justin Hilliard"
                    ],
                "description" : "Your NEW source for Late Model Camaro Parts & Accessories!",
                "publisher" : "Justin Hilliard ",
                "potentialAction" :
                    [ 
                        "@type" : "SearchAction", 
                        "target" : "https://shop.bcsauto.com/search.html?q={search_term}&go=Search", 
                        "query-input" : "required name=search_term"
                    ] 
            },
            {   
                "@type" : "Organization",
                "name" : "BCS Auto",
                "url" : "http://www.bcsauto.com",
                "logo" : "https://shop.bcsauto.com/files/images/logo.png",
                "foundingDate" : "2016",
                "founders": 
                [
                    {
                        "@type": "Person",
                        "name": "Justin Hilliard"
                    },
                ],
            }, 
                {   
                    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
                    "contactType" : "Sales",
                    "telephone" : "[+1-602-730-6415]",
                    "email" : "sales@bcsauto.com",
                    "areaServed" : "US"
                },
                {
                    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
                    "contactType" : "Customer Support",
                    "telephone" : "[+1-602-730-6415]",
                    "email" : "support@bcsauto.com",
                    "areaServed" : "US",
                    "sameAs" :
                        [
                            "https://www.facebook.com/OfficialBCSAuto",
                            "https://instagram.com/officialbcsauto",
                            "https://www.linkedin.com/company/bcsauto" 
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
            "author" : 
                [
                    "@type" : "Person",
                    "name" : "Justin Hilliard"
                ],
```

```json
            "potentialAction" :
                [ 
                    "@type" : "SearchAction", 
                    "target" : "https://shop.bcsauto.com/search.html?q={search_term}&go=Search", 
                    "query-input" : "required name=search_term"
                ]
```

`[` `]` are for arrays, `{` `}` are for objects. In the snippets above, you have objects, so you have to use curly brackets instead of square brackets.

```json
            "founders": 
            [
                {
                    "@type": "Person",
                    "name": "Justin Hilliard"
                },
            ],
```

In the snippet above, you have an array with only one object. Whether or not you keep the array (with only one value, it’s not needed), you have to remove the last two `,`, because the object is the last value in the array, and the array is the last value in the parent object.

Comment: Thanks, you rock. I will give that a shot! I was under the (mistaken) impression that the brackets and curly brackets were just meant to alternate or something, but I was shooting in the dark on that one. :)

And I actually did have the commas in the appropriate places at some point, but I had 6 versions of this being edited at once while trying to figure it out, and I must've grabbed a slightly older copy.

Comment: @JustinHilliard: If it solved your problem, you can mark this answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark next to it). -- By the way, I think your Schema.org could be improved: it’s typically better to connect the various entities via properties instead of providing only top-level items in `@graph`. For example, you could say that the `Organization` is the `publisher` of the `WebSite`, and that the `Organization` has the `ContactPoint` as `contactPoint`.

Comment: Thank you for that. This is my first time implementing Schema.org data as such.

I will definitely make the change regarding the Organization being the publisher of the website, but I'm not sure what you mean about adding the ContactPoint as contactPoint?

Comment: @JustinHilliard: If the `ContactPoint` belongs to the `Organization`, you would say: `Organization` [`contactPoint`](https://schema.org/contactPoint) `ContactPoint`. So the `contactPoint` property has an array as value, with the `ContactPoint` objects as array values.

Comment: That makes a little more sense. I'll give that a short later in the day and see how it goes. Thanks for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @unor, I was able to sort this question out! I was mixing up my brackets and curly brakcets because I didn't understand arrays and objects.

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "url": "https://www.bcsauto.com",
      "name": "BCS Auto",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Justin Hilliard"
      },
      "description": "Your NEW source for Late Model Camaro Parts & Accessories!",
      "publisher": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Justin Hilliard"
      },
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://shop.bcsauto.com/search.html?q={search_term}&go=Search",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "BCS Auto",
      "url": "http://www.bcsauto.com",
      "logo": "https://shop.bcsauto.com/files/images/logo.png",
      "foundingDate": "2016",
      "founders": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Justin Hilliard"
      },
      "ContactPoint": [
        {
          "@type": "ContactPoint",
          "contactType": "Sales",
          "telephone": "[+1-602-730-6415]",
          "email": "sales@bcsauto.com",
          "areaServed": "US"
        },
        {
          "@type": "ContactPoint",
          "contactType": "Customer Support",
          "telephone": "[+1-602-730-6415]",
          "email": "support@bcsauto.com",
          "areaServed": "US",
          "sameAs": [
            "https://www.facebook.com/OfficialBCSAuto",
            "https://instagram.com/officialbcsauto",
            "https://www.linkedin.com/company/bcsauto"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```